# return an array of pointer, return type?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I have a function..

```
char ** getCommand()
{ 
    char *commandArray[BUFSIZ]; //declaring an array of char pointers
    // i m doing things to array

    return commandArray;
}
```

I am getting an error saying "conflicting types".  what is the type of commandArray? It is a pointer to a pointer right?

I tried char *getcommand()...that didn't work either. I am calling this function in main
so I have delcared..

```
main()
{
    char *commands;

    commands = getCommand();  //this didn't work 

    // So I redeclared...
    char *commands[BUFSIZ];

    commands = getCommand();  //this didn't work either.
}
```

Whats going on? I have never worked w/ array of pointers before...
someone simplify the problem...and give me some kind of hint pls..

**EDIT**

Ok thanks for the suggestions...didn't work...

I am pasting the code...suggested changes reflected..getting same error, saying the getCommand has conflicting error types.

```
char **getCommand()
{
    int command_num;
    char input[BUFSIZ];
    char **commandArray;

    command_num = 0;
    commandArray = (char**) malloc (BUFSIZ * sizeof(char));

    fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin);
    commandArray[command_num] = strtok(input, " "); /*breaks a string of commands into
                                                      tokens*/
    while (commandArray[command_num]!= NULL)
    {
        printf ("%s\n", commandArray[command_num]);
        command_num++;
        commandArray[command_num] = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }

    commandArray[command_num] = NULL;  /*very imp - adds null in the last position*/
    return commandArray;
}
```

Comment: Please post a minimal, complete example that demonstrate the problem, the whole problem and nothing but the problem.

Comment: you might try posting your revision as a comment for one of the answers -- what didn't work?

Comment: @Chris: the problem is fixed now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You have a problem there. You're declaring the array as a local variable.
This means it will die (be realeased) in the end of the block.
if you want to return it you need to dynamically allocate it  (and remember to free it later)

```
char** getCommand()
{ 
    char **commandArray = (char **)malloc(BUFSIZ* sizeof(char*));

    // i m doing things to array

    return commandArray;

}
```

Comment: The input array - which commandArray points to - is also on the stack.

Comment: Noob question: is this technically still an array? I've been finding things over the Internet that say these sorts of pointers aren't technically arrays.

Comment: @weberc2 : it's not an array type. An array type looks like this: `type variablename[N];` .. But, c++ allows you to use the [] operator on pointers, which just uses pointer arithmetic to move through the memory as if it was an array. So if you look at the type, it's a pointer type, not an array (important fact for type safety). But for any other purpose it works like an array.

Answer (score 3):

With

```
char **cmdArray
```

you have a pointer to pointers. But the pointer does not have a valid value. Use `malloc` to reserve some space for a few pointers and assign that value to the pointer

```
cmdArray = malloc(20 * sizeof (char*));
```

Now, `cmdArray` points to an area of 20 pointers. But none of those 20 pointers have a valid value. You need to allocate space for each of those 20 pointers

```
for (k = 0; k < 20; k++) {
    cmdArray[k] = malloc(BUFSIZ);
}
```

Now, you're good to go :)
`cmdArray` points to 20 valid pointers and each of those pointers points to a memory area capable of holding BUFSIZ characters (or strings of up to `BUFSIZ - 1` length).

To deallocate the space you need to do the reverse: first the 20 pointers and last the pointer to pointers

```
for (k = 0; k < 20; k++) {
    free(cmdArray[k]);
}
free(cmdArray);
```

**Don't forget to check the return value of `malloc` before using the memory for real**

Comment: Best answer because they actually mentioned `free` which you MUST USE or you will leak memory.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is commandArray is an array of pointers which is stored in getCommand()'s stack frame, so this is, technically speaking, undefined behavior. The solution is to change commandArray to a char ** and use malloc() to allocate the whole array.

Answer (score 2):

Following are the 2 changes needed:

- Should not return reference to local variable (which is stored on function stack), instead allocate memory from heap and returns its reference.
- Receiving pointer in main should also be of type char **

---

```
char **getCommand(){
     char **command = (char **) malloc(N*BUFSIZE);
     //Do something to command array
     return command;
}

int main(){
     char **commands;
     commands = getCommand();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically allocating the commandArray as suggested by others is insufficient as the allocated array being returned contains pointers into the input array and the input array is also on the stack so goes out of scope when the function getCommand() returns.

To see if this is the problem change:

```
char input[BUFSIZ];
```

To

```
static char input[BUFSIZ];
```